# Unpivot multiple column with empyt value

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, unpivot

I have a table **QUESTIONAIRE** with columns **ID, Q1, Q2, Q3, R1, R2, R3.** Data is like:

```
ID , Q1 , Q2 , Q3 , R1 , R2 , R3 
==   ==   ==   ==   ==   ==   ==
1,   A,   B,   C,   Y,  NULL,  N
2,   Aa,  Bb,  Cc,  -,  N,     Y
```

I want to get it arranged like the following:

```
ID, QUESTION, ANSWER
==  ========  ======
1,   A,       Y
1,   B,       NULL
1,   C,       N
2,   Aa,      -
2,   Bb,      N
2,   Cc,      Y
```

Comment: ...and you may wish to correct the spelling in your title and question body too.

Comment: If you have any control over your database structure, consider changing to something different. You don't want to have to change your structure just to add new questions or responses, or to duplicate things like FOREIGN KEY relationships multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `UNION`
Assuming you're creating a new table `unpivoted`
The insert will be:

```
INSERT INTO unpivoted
SELECT
id, Q1, R1

UNION

SELECT
id, Q2, R2

UNION

SELECT
id, Q3, R3
```

Notice that id will repeat itself 3 times, I would recommend andding a unique id for the `unpivoted` table

Answer (score 0):

Several databases support lateral joins.  This is a more efficient and effective way to express this logic.

In SQL Server, this would look like:

```
select q.id, v.q, v.r
from questionnaire q cross apply
     (values (q1, r1), (q2, r2), (q3, r3)) v(q, r);
```

Oracle and Postgres support similar logic although the syntax is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

If your Database is `SQL Server` or `Oracle`, then use `unpivot` keyword as below with the common syntax :

```
with t(ID , Q1 , Q2 , Q3 , R1 , R2 , R3) as
(
 select 1,  'A',  'B',  'C',  'Y', NULL, 'N' union all
 select 2, 'Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc', '-' ,  'N', 'Y'  
), u2 as
(
select ID, QUESTION, R1, R2, R3, 
       row_number() over (partition by ID order by QUESTION) as rn
  from 
  (
   select u.* from
     (select t.*
        from t) p
   unpivot 
  (
  QUESTION for Title in (Q1,Q2,Q3)
  ) u
  ) u1
)
select ID, QUESTION, 
       case when rn = 1 then R1 
            when rn = 2 then R2 
            when rn = 3 then R3 
       end as ANSWER
  from u2;

ID   QUESTION   ANSWER
--   --------   ------
1    A          Y
1    B  
1    C          N
2    Aa         -
2    Bb         N
2    Cc         Y
```

with an exception related to the above queries for the sample data, `union all` should be replaced with `from dual union all` for `Oracle` Database.

<kbd>[Demo for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9cf2ee140aef6d5fd7db579fe72de5e8)</kbd>